# em.merge doesn't generate update statement

Tags: java, hibernate, constraints

I'm using JPA 2.0 and hibernate in the project and faced the problem:
em.merge() doesn't generate the update statement.

The detail situation is:
I have an entity, which is successfully persisted. It has a foreign key on other entity, mapped like:

```
@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, optional = false)
@JoinColumn(name = "ENTITY2_ID", referencedColumnName = "ID")
@ForeignKey(name = "FK_ENTITY2_PS")
private Entity2 entity2;
```

It is created a bit later and persisted too. After that I make

```
entity1.setEntity2(entity2);
em.merge(entity1);
```

and see the log: hibernate doesn't generate the update statement for that and my application crashes with constraint violation. Is this a bug? Or am I doing something wrong?

**UPD**
The logging is turned on and I see inserts there. 
The method where `em.merge()` occurs is inside `@Stateless` bean, which methods have `TransactionalAttribute.REQUIRED` by default.

Comment: You're probably doing something wrong. The problem is probably due to the ConstraintViolationException.

Comment: Where is the method that contains em.merge() being called from? the annotation TransactionalAttribute.REQUIRED does not create a new Transaction, so this will not work unless you are already in a Transaction (e.g. the calling method is annotated @Transactional).  Try anotating the method with @Transactional or you could use TransactionalAttribute.REQUIRES_NEW - although you should think that through as it means it will always create a new transaction whatever

Comment: Also, whilst it wouldn't be causing this problem, I generally avoid using merge() unless dealing with detached entities - if you load any object inside a transaction, then any changes made to that object within the same transaction are persisted automatically once the transaction finishes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a couple of things that could be going wrong, but you would need to check/show us the logs of whats going on to be sure.  If you havent already, you should turn your logging up to debug (something like this in log4j.properties):

```
log4j.logger.net.sf.hibernate=debug
log4j.logger.net.sf.hibernate.SQL=debug
```

and turn on show sql (In the persistence unit in persistence.xml):

```
<property name="hibernate.show.sql" value="true" />
```

Also, we would need to see the context of the merge - I assume it is being dones inside a Spring managed bean? Also, have you marked the method that calls em.merge() as @Transactional? if you are not inside a valid transaction it will probably fail to persist it pretty silently

---

**UPDATED:**

Where is the method that contains em.merge() being called from?

The annotation TransactionalAttribute.REQUIRED does not create a new Transaction, so this will not work unless you are already in a Transaction (e.g. the calling method is annotated @Transactional).

Try anotating the method with @Transactional or you could use TransactionalAttribute.REQUIRES_NEW - although you should think that through as it means it will always create a new transaction whatever

Answer (score 0):

I think you're missing cascade settings.. try -

```
@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, optional = false, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
```